# Change the sequence in a given order

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sequence

I have a query where I am getting the list of data as below:

Where each content is having a specific category and each category is having a checkbox for playing it based on category or not.

```
Id  Category    content_type   Content   IsCategorywise
=====================================================
1   ABC         Image          content1  1
2   ABC         Image          content2  1
3   EFG         Video          content3  0
4   EFG         Image          content4  0
5   EFG         Image          content5  0
6   XYZ         Image          content6  1
7   XYZ         Image          content7  1
```

So here I am getting 3 groups:

```
Id  Category    content_type   Content   IsCategorywise
=====================================================
1   ABC         Image          content1  1
2   ABC         Image          content2  1

Id  Category    content_type   Content   IsCategorywise
=====================================================
3   EFG         Video          content3  0
4   EFG         Image          content4  0
5   EFG         Image          content5  0

Id  Category    content_type   Content   IsCategorywise
=====================================================
6   XYZ         Image          content6  1
7   XYZ         Image          content7  1
```

Now I want the sequence as below if all content's `IsCategoryWise` is `1`:

1st content of first group, 1st of second group, 1st of third group
2nd content of first group, 2nd of second group, 2nd of third group
3rd content of first group, 3rd of second group, 3rd of third group

But if any of the category group has `IsCategoryWise` is `0` then they will be in the same sequence all along:

1st content of first group, (All 3 content of second group), 1st of third group
2nd content of first group, (All 3 content of second group), 2nd of third group

Desired Output:

```
Id  Category    content_type   Content   IsCategorywise
=====================================================
1   ABC         Image          content1  1
3   EFG         Video          content3  0
4   EFG         Image          content4  0
5   EFG         Image          content5  0
6   XYZ         Image          content6  1

2   ABC         Image          content2  1
3   EFG         Video          content3  0
4   EFG         Image          content4  0
5   EFG         Image          content5  0
7   XYZ         Image          content7  1
```

How is it possible in SQL Server query or in C# linq ?

Answer (score 1):

please refer to in-code comments for explanation

```
-- create sample table
declare @tbl table
(
    Id              int,
    Category        varchar(10),
    content_type    varchar(10),  
    Content         varchar(10), 
    IsCategorywise  int
)

-- insert sample data
insert into @tbl 
values
    (1,   'ABC',         'Image',          'content1',  1),
    (2,   'ABC',         'Image',          'content2',  1),
    (3,   'EFG',         'Video',          'content3',  0),
    (4,   'EFG',         'Image',          'content4',  0),
    (5,   'EFG',         'Image',          'content5',  0),
    (6,   'XYZ',         'Image',          'content6',  1),
    (7,   'XYZ',         'Image',          'content7',  1)

-- the query
; with 
-- use numbers / tally table if you have one. 
numbers as
(
    select  n = 1
    union all
    select  n = n + 1
    from    numbers
    where   n < 10
),
cte as
(
    select  *,      
            -- Group wise IsCategorywise value
            GrpCW   = min(IsCategorywise) over (partition by Category),
            -- generate row_number for GrpCW = 1 for each category order by Id
            rn  = case  when    min(IsCategorywise) over (partition by Category) = 1
                        then    row_number() over (partition by Category order by Id)
                        end
    from    @tbl
),
cte2 as
(
    select  *, 
            -- m is for repeating the GrpCW = 0 for each grouping
            m = case when GrpCW = 1 then 1 else max(rn) over () end
    from    cte
)
-- basically you want to order by "rn" but for cases where IsCategorywise = 0,
-- you want to repeat it. That is where the inner join to "numbers" comes in
select  Id, Category, content_type, Content, IsCategorywise
from    cte2 c
        inner join numbers n    on  n.n <= c.m
order by coalesce(rn, n), Category, Id

/*
Id          Category   content_type Content    IsCategorywise
----------- ---------- ------------ ---------- --------------
1           ABC        Image        content1   1
3           EFG        Video        content3   0
4           EFG        Image        content4   0
5           EFG        Image        content5   0
6           XYZ        Image        content6   1
2           ABC        Image        content2   1
3           EFG        Video        content3   0
4           EFG        Image        content4   0
5           EFG        Image        content5   0
7           XYZ        Image        content7   1
*/
```

Comment: What's all this? Surely you could provide some explanation rather than a code dump?

Comment: please refer to in-query comments for explanation

Comment: Please edit so that the in-query comments are regular text - no-one will read this otherwise.

Comment: @Squirrel I want this sequence to be repeated till the MAX count of each category. So if the item is completed for one category then it should start again with first.

Comment: @VishalSuthar, maybe you can include such scenario in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Id
  ,Category
  ,content_type
  ,Content
  ,IsCategorywise
FROM (

    SELECT
      Id
      ,Category
      ,content_type
      ,Content
      ,IsCategorywise
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Category,Id) as orderby
    FROM myTable
    WHERE IsCategorywise=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Id
      ,Category
      ,content_type
      ,Content
      ,IsCategorywise
      ,1.5
    FROM myTable
    WHERE IsCategorywise=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Id
      ,Category
      ,content_type
      ,Content
      ,IsCategorywise
      ,3.5
    FROM myTable
    WHERE IsCategorywise=0
) X
ORDER BY orderby
```

The field 'orderby' makes the right ordering.